# DD-WRT AP with ethernet bridge

Tags: debian, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point, kali-linux, traffic-filtering

Good evening everyone!

I'm looking to host a wifi access point using my DD-WRT (Linksys WRT54G) with a PC running Kali Linux 1.1.0 (Debian) to monitor the traffic. Effectively the traffic would flow like this:

```
Cable ISP -> Modem/Router Combo -> Dumb switch -> Linux PC -> Wireless AP -> Clients
```

The problem lies within the Linux PC, possibly the DD-WRT AP. I've been trying to use different tools such as the bridge-utils package and iptables with absolutely no luck. I just want the linux PC to act as a passive monitor on the network.

Everything in this network is connected with Ethernet, the only wireless entity will be the wireless AP.

I just want the router to work as though it's connected right to the modem/router combo (which has been tested to work, router config is good I think...)

Thanks to anyone that takes a whack at this crazy little project of mine. I'm open to any soultion, bonus points for simplicity or scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify iptables to copy all packets into new port, associated with IP of collect machine.
First problem to solve is ROUTE and --tee module functionality was not loaded...you have to run on shell:

```
/sbin/modprobe ipt_ROUTE
```

Then, 'ROUTE' enables router to receive the packet and route it towards an interface or a host. Using it with the '-tee' switch, which results in the packet being copied but the original packet traverses through the router as
normal and undisturbed by new iptables rules

```
/usr/sbin/iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -j ROUTE --gw <ip_collect_machine> --tee

/usr/sbin/iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -j ROUTE --gw
<ip_collect_machine> --tee -d ! <internal_network>/<mask>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with another approach: Use port mirroring on the WRT54G and connect your linux PC to the mirrored port to monitor the traffic. Alternative: replace your dumb switch with a hub (a hub keeps sending out all traffic on all ports in contrast to a switch) and connect PC and WRT54G to it.
If none of the above is an option then we need more details on what you tried until now.